# Windows 2000 on Compaq Presario says no audio devices are installed

Tags: audio, drivers, troubleshooting, windows-2000, compaq-laptop

I was given a very old Compaq Presario laptop (Model M2000) and asked to make it usable. It had Windows XP and a lot of viruses; the audio was horrible, with too much noise in output.

I had a Windows 2000 Installation CD, hence decided to wipe out the hard disk and install Windows 2000. I planned to copy over lots of MP3 content and very old videos with VLC 1.1.11 installed. If the audio was still bad, I would attach some external speakers.

Installation of Windows 2000 went well, VLC 1.1.11 also got installed.
Now when I tried playing some MIDI content, VLC threw error about some Entry Point not found in kernel32.dll (I will try to fix this by trying out VLC 0.9.9, but this Post is not about that)
I tried Windows Media Player and it said "no audio devices are installed"

What could be the problem ?
How do I troubleshoot it ?
In case this is a software Issue, how do I get the appropriate Drivers for the sound card ?
In case this is a hardware Issue, Is there any way out ?

Comment: What is your Compaq Presario model, and why don't you re-install XP?

Comment: @harrymc , It is not my laptop, it belongs to my uncle, who does not have any of the original CDs or license keys or anything other than the laptop. I do not have XP Installation CD or license key. If I can make the audio work, then my uncle can use the laptop to listen to MP3 content and play some old movies. I may have to go with some old 32bt Distro of Linux.

Comment: @harrymc , it is Model M2000. I will check for audio drivers for this !

Answer (score 1):

For such an old operating system version there are no drivers to be found
on the Compaq-become-HP site.

I may have managed to find the one for the sound control unit:
ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp30001-30500/sp30399.exe.

The drivers for XP may also work on Windows 2000. Here are some references :

- [Compaq Presario M2000 Notebook PC Windows XP drivers](http://hpnotebookdrivers.com/compaq-presario-m2000-notebook-pc-windows-xp-drivers/).
- [HP Compaq Presario M2000 drivers](https://driverscollection.com/?H=Compaq%20Presario%20M2000&By=HP)

Comment: +1 , Thanks for trying to help me ! I tried https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/Audio-driver-for-Presario-M2000-Win-7-32-bit/td-p/4967665 which said I have to execute (or extract) sp30399.exe (your first web-link) and then use device manager to install that driver, but it failed during extraction itself. I also tried the Drivers for XP (your second and third web-links), but both sp28482.exe & sp28483.exe failed. I will continue web searching .....

Comment: Yes, you will need to search, but be careful to use only download sites that are well-known. There are ways to install XP, and you might search for them too.